# how to do a autocomplete for a dropdownlistfor in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, dropdownlistfor

I have a cities list in a dropdown where up on selecting a city,i will get Zip codes for the selected city in the next dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerAddress.CityID, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "Id", "Data"),"--Select--",  new {data_required = true, error_label_id="lblPersonalCity"})</span>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerAddress.ZipID, new SelectList(Model.Zips, "Id", "Name"), "--Select--",  new {data_required = true, error_label_id="lblPersonalZip"})
```

Every thing works fine.But now my requirement is to change this Zip Dropdown to Autocomplete using Jquery.

I am able to use autocomplete for an input textbox for a static data.Like following.

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableZips = [
  {id:0,value:"37210"},
  { id: 1, value: "37212" }
];
$( "#zips" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableZips       
});
});
</script>
```

But when i try to do the same in the city dropdown change event,autocomplete is not firing.

i fetch cities like following

```
myapplication.CustomerManager.GetCities = function (StateId, dropdownId) {
    myapplication.navigation.ajaxGetJson(myapplication.rootPath + "api/Common/GetCitiesByStateID?stateId=" + StateId, null, function (data) {
        myapplication.helpers.populateDropDown($("#" + dropdownId), data, "Data", "Id", "--Select--", "");
    });
};
```

i fetch zips like following

```
 myapplication.CustomerManager.GetZips = function (CityId, dropdownId) {
    myapplication.navigation.ajaxGetJson(myapplication.rootPath + "api/Common/GetZips?CityId=" + CityId, null, function (data) {
        myapplication.helpers.populateDropDown($("#" + dropdownId), data, "Name", "Id", "--Select--", "");
    });
};
```

My city dropdown change looks like this

```
  $("#CustomerAddress_CityID").live("change", function () {
    var cityNo = $("#CustomerAddress_CityID").val();
    if (cityNo != "") {
        myapplication.CustomerManager.GetZips($(this).val(), "CustomerAddress_ZipID");
        if ($("#CustomerAddress_ZipID").find('option').find("[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").length > 1) {

            $("#CustomerAddress_ZipID").attr('data-required', false);
            $('#CustomerAddress_ZipID').attr("style", "border: 1px solid #ccc !important");

        }

        else {

            $('#CustomerAddress_ZipID').attr("style", "border: 1px solid #FF0033 !important");
            $('#CustomerAddress_ZipID').attr('data-required', true);
        }
    }

    else {
        $("#CustomerAddress_ZipID").val('--Select--');
        $('#CustomerAddress_ZipID').attr("style", "border: 1px solid #FF0033 !important");
        $('#CustomerAddress_ZipID').attr('data-required', true);
    }
});
```

Is there any extension like thing for DropdownlistFor to makeit like autocomplte?
Or mandatory to use input textbox.
How to pass the selected ZipId in autocomplete?

Thanks in advance.

Any working model in jsfiddle would be much helpful

Edit:
I am trying to write the following code in city dropdown change

```
  $("#CustomerAddress_CityID").live("change", function () {
     var myZips = null;
    var cityNo = $("#CustomerAddress_CityID").val();
    if (cityNo != "") {
     myapplication.navigation.ajaxGetJson(myapplication.rootPath + "api/Common/GetZips?CityId=" + cityNo, null, function (data) {
         myZips = data;
           $("#CustomerAddress_ZipID").autocomplete({
            source: myZips 
               });
        }
    });
```

here i declared "myZips" globally and fetching all zips based on cityid selected.
This approach is not working.
But when the same global variable contains any hard code data,it works fine.
if i declare my gloabl variable as follows:

```
 var myZips = [
            { id: 0, value: "37210" },
            { id: 1, value: "37211" }
        ];
```

autocomplete works now.
whats the problem here?

my json returns like this :

```
0: {Id: 1, Name: "37201", Data: null, Code: null}
```

Code: null
Data: null
Id: 1
Name: "37201"

Is there any problem with json data

Comment: Well, you can't add auto-complete functionality to a drop-down-list because that element doesn't involve text input.  How would auto-complete even work for that input?  If the requirement is to change the drop-down-list to an auto-complete text input then I imagine you'll need to change it to a text input.  What exactly is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: i am unable to store the zips(based on the city selected) in a global variable so that i can use this global variable for input text autocomplete

Comment: check this:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/01/searchable-dropdown-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: @Santosh: Why are you unable to do that?  If the value needs to be accessed outside the scope of that initialization function (for example, to update it from an AJAX callback) then it needs to exist outside of that scope.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad,the given link is not opening

Comment: @Santosh: The link is working.  It basically just recommends a different jQuery plugin: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @David Edited my Question.Can you please check